# is there a way to convert data from SSAS dimensional representation back into relational representation?

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube, rolap

I was wandering, if there was a way to reverse engineer an SSAS OLAP cube back into its original relational representation.
Is such a thing possible?

Comment: When you say reverse engineer, are you talking about a query to get data back into a tabular format? Or are you talking about recreating the tables and that are being used for Facts and Dimensions?

Comment: I'm talking about getting data back into Tabular format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set up a linked server on my Sql Server and then use an OpenQuery to get data out. It is a little bit ugly, but you can do it like below:

```
SELECT "[Dimension Name].[Hierarchy Name].[Department Name].[MEMBER_CAPTION]" as Department,
  round("[Measures].[Some Calculation]",3) as Value,
  'Value_Descr' as Value_Descr
FROM OPENQUERY(SSAS_Link,' SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Some Calculation] } ON COLUMNS
    ,NON EMPTY {([Date Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Code].ALLMEMBERS * [Dimension Name].[Hierarchy Name].[Lowest Hierarchy Level Field].ALLMEMBERS) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION
    ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM (
    SELECT ({ [Dimension Name].[Field to Filter].& [Key of Field to filer] }) ON COLUMNS
    FROM (SELECT ([Fiscal Week Code - Last Week]) ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube Name])  )
    WHERE ([Dimension Name].[Field to Filter].& [Key of Field to filer]) ')
```

Comment: I wrote a post about creating a [Linked Server to Analysis Services](https://bizintelsolutions.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/openquery-from-analysis-services/) if you need to set one up.